# Spilled tea on laptop; still working, should I service it anyway? Displayport dead

Tags: hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop, water-damage

I need some advice. I spilled tea on the left side of my X230T.

I did the normal out with the battery and dry procedure. The laptop works now. Not much got in the keyboard, much spilled against the ports on the left side. The displayport is not working, but the USB and VGA is working. But I think some water got inside the fan vent and that might in the long run rust up the system board.

Should I get a service on it just to be sure? Check for damage and maybe replace the systemboard? Will a new board fix the displayport or did it shortcut something in the CPU, since the the gpu is integrated in it? I don't now, I could just use it as long as it works and get a new one when or if it dies, but I would like to try to be preventive if possible.
If a service now will prevent it from kicking the boot in 4 months time it's worth it for me.

Comment: "normal dry procedure"? Pat it down with a towel or take it apart? Get a big bag of rice and throw the laptop in? How long has it been?

Comment: @Logman, No rice. I removed the keyboard and let a fan blow trough it during the night. I did see some slight water on the far left on top of the black plastic.

Comment: could take weeks or even months to dry completely, depends on the environment. Rice can/will remove moisture and speed it up. The laptop I am currently using had a major spill, took months to even get it to turn on and I took it apart for the most part and aired it out when it happened.  Works perfectly now.